# shell: Replace all occurances of particular text contained between arbitrary "start" and "finish"

Tags: regex, replace, full-text-search

I want a one liner run from nix shell to replace all occurances of particular text contained between arbitrary "start" and "finish", e.g. in

```
nfw987__qrh fwef_start_hf9
832j fsjdlkfa;jd(&6^)lf dfs
ahlkj;fd__sajhfds
dsfahs__lkjfdsaf jlkfdsa_finish_jfoi__edwp
```

replace all `__` which are between `_start_` and `_finish_` with `()`.

I've tried web search but all I find is "simple" replace. I'm writing a code to do that, but maybe that IMHO common task has been solved already with sed, perl, awk etc.

Comment: this may assist http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.24

Answer (score 0):

As per al76 link, `sed` can be easily used for such cases (text is also replaced on start and end lines regardless of where on that line text is, that does not answer my question exactly, but for my current task it is sufficient):

> to address the lines between two regular expressions, RE1 and RE2, one
>   would do this: '/RE1/,/RE2/{commands;}'

`sed '/_start_/,/_finish_/{s/__/\(\)/g}' tst2.txt`